# Parameter @roomid must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been messing around with some new code that I wrote in these last few days, but I keep getting into trouble with it and I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

My current code is as follows:

```
                                    dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `roomtype`, `caption`, `owner`, `description`, `category`, `state`, `users_now`, `users_max`, `model_name`, `public_ccts`, `score`, `tags`, `icon_bg`, `icon_fg`, `icon_items`, `password`, `wallpaper`, `floor`, `landscape`, `allow_pets`, `allow_pets_eat`, `allow_walkthrough`, `allow_hidewall`, `wallthick`, `floorthick`, `achievement`, `group_id`, `game_id`, `mute_settings`, `ban_settings`, `kick_settings`) VALUES " +
                                    "(NULL, 'private', 'VIP CADEAU: Penthouse', @username, 'Ontvang deze kamer GRATIS bij het lid worden van VIP (http://wonderhotel.nl/vip).', 11, 'open', 0, 25, 'model_i', '', 1, '', 1, 0, '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '1', '0', '0', '0', -2, -2, 0, 0, 0, '0', '1', '1');");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("username", Session.GetUser().Username);

                                    dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
                                    dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
                                    dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `items` (`user_id`, `room_id`, `base_item`, `extra_data`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `rot`, `wall_pos`, `rareid`) VALUES " +
                                    "(@id, @roomid, 99036, '0', 6, 6, 0.0002, 0, '', 0);");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("id", Session.GetUser().Id);
                                    dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
                                        dbClient.runQuery();
                                    dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO `items` (`user_id`, `room_id`, `base_item`, `extra_data`, `x`, `y`, `z`, `rot`, `wall_pos`, `rareid`) VALUES " +
                                    "(@id, @roomid, 71000250, '', 11, 1, 0, 0, '', 0);");
                                    dbClient.addParameter("id", Session.GetUser().Id);
                                    dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
                                    dbClient.runQuery();
```

But when running this code, I keep getting a MySQL error that my parameter @roomid isn't defined, even though I've defined it at line 12...

Comment: It looks like the `dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");` does not belong there....

Comment: I need to get the inserted `NULL` value and insert it in the following query afterwards. That value should be defined as @roomid.

Comment: Shouldn't that be after the `dbClient.runQuery();`?

Comment: My mistake - fixed it ;). But the error is still showing up.

Comment: You probably also want to add another `dbClient.runQuery();` if you want the last insert_id....

Comment: Forgot to add it to the main post, but added it in my code, and it doesn't work. There must be an easier and cleaner solution to define @roomid as the last inserted row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed a part of your code, leaving this:

```
dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
dbClient.runQuery();

dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO....");
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
dbClient.runQuery();

dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO ....");
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString());
dbClient.runQuery();
```

The first time you use `dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString()`, `dbClient` still contains the result of the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` query.

But the second time you executed a new query, clearing the result. So you probably want to store it in a variable, for example:

```
dbClient.setQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
dbClient.runQuery();
string roomId=dbClient.getRow()[0].ToString();

dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO....");
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", roomId);
dbClient.runQuery();

dbClient.setQuery("INSERT INTO ....");
dbClient.addParameter("roomid", roomId);
dbClient.runQuery();
```